# Rails extract data strange behaviour from Array of Array containing Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this response from an

`{"Dates"=>[[{"DateString"=>"2016-09-01"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-02"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-03"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-04"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-05"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-06"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-07"}, {"DateString"=>"2016-09-08"}], [{"MinPrice"=>3669.0, "QuoteDateTime"=>"2016-09-01T12:49:10"}, {"MinPrice"=>3216.0, "QuoteDateTime"=>"2016-09-01T15:53:40"}, {"MinPrice"=>2668.0, "QuoteDateTime"=>"2016-09-01T13:48:21"}]], "Places"=>[{"PlaceId"=>42850, "...}`

This is my code

```
<% @result["Dates"].each do |f| %>
    <% Array.wrap(f).each do |seg| %> 
        <%= seg['DateString'] %> - <%= seg['MinPrice'] %> 
        <br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is like an Array of Array containing hashes but when I try to extract `DateString` and `MinPrice` together, I am getting a result like this

```
2016-09-01 -  
2016-09-02 -  
2016-09-03 -  
2016-09-04 -  
2016-09-05 -  
2016-09-06 -  
2016-09-07 -  
2016-09-08 -  
- 3669.0  
- 3230.0  
- 2809.0  
- 2668.0  
- 3216.0  
- 2507.0  
- 3216.0  
- 2848.0  
- 3216.0
```

What I am trying is rather this arrangement

```
2016-09-01 - 3669.0  
2016-09-02 - 3230.0  
2016-09-03 - 2809.0  
2016-09-04 - 2668.0
```

i.e., Datestring and Minprice together

**Where is the code not correct?**

---

Also, strangely, if the code is rearranged like this
`<%= seg['MinPrice'] %> - <%= seg['DateString'] %> <br>`

It would still show up like this

```
- 2016-09-01  
- 2016-09-02  
- 2016-09-03   
.  
.  
.    
3669.0 -  
3230.0 -  
2809.0 -
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: Can you reformat the code please

Comment: You mean the API response or the View code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<% @result["Dates"][0].zip(@result["Dates"][1]).each do |f,a| %>
  <%= "#{f['DateString']} - #{a['MinPrice']}" if f && a %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

It's far from pretty, but it might be a good start.

Comment: Yeah that works! Any reference in the docs, as to where to make it better, as you said  it's not perfect?

Comment: Glad it works! As for the code, I was only referring to it as 'far from pretty' because the first line is long and kind of hard to read. The second line sort of describes what we are doing with the first line though, so it should be fine. You could add a comment just to be safe!

Comment: That was helpful. From what you did, I was able to find about `transpose` and `each_with_index` as well. Useful. Thanks.